# tensorflow map function not being invoked

Tags: python, tensorflow

based on my understanding of map function in tensorflow, I expected that my_map would be invoked 60,000 times but it was invoked only once.

Output

> Using TensorFlow backend. (60000, 28, 28)
>    Tensor("map/while/TensorArrayReadV3:0", shape=(28, 28), dtype=uint8)
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.datasets import mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()


def my_map(elem):
    print(elem)
    return elem


print(train_images.shape)

tf_map = tf.map_fn(fn=my_map, elems=train_images)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf_map)
```

What did I do wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The print in the my_map won't work for printing. Please, test this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.datasets import mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()


def my_map(elem):
    #print(elem)
    elem = elem + 1
    return elem


print(train_images.shape)

tf_map = tf.map_fn(fn=my_map, elems=train_images)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(tf_map[0,0]))
```

Comment: you were right. Sorry, my bad, I inspecting some variables and since most of them were zeros i thought it was not working. thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

According to the following description for map_fn.
(https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn)

The "map_fn" returns tensor which was manipulated by the function in the parameter "fn".
In your case, train_images first dimension number is 6,000. The "map_fn" applied my_map function 6,000 times and return the result. That is why you just saw the result 1 line.

You could check it just print the tf_map.shape for your confirmation.

When you need to print the result do this:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(tf_map))
```

Comment: if my_map had been applied 60,000, how come I don't see 60,000 print(elem). this is what is bothering me. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The "map_fn" is the utility of massive data manipulation, I thought. You may refer my new following codes.